# Linux sort command not working with hyphens and colons in string

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, uniq

There's no shortage of questions and answers related to this question but I cannot find any specifically talking about multiple special characters causing issues...only about one particular.

My dataset example contains both hyphens and colons, where the hyphens show up in the first section of the string and the colon is the separator between "columns" I'd like to sort...for example:

```
s3:GetObject
ssm:GetParameter
ssm:GetParameters
ssm:GetParametersByPath
secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
cognito-identity:GetOpenIdToken
cognito-identity:GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity
cognito-identity:GetCredentialsForIdentity
connect:GetFederationToken
ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
gamelift:RequestUploadCredentials
sts:GetFederationToken
sts:GetSessionToken
s3:GetObject
secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
ssm:GetParameter
ssm:GetParameters
ssm:GetParametersByPath
```

I'd like to do a `sort | uniq` or equivalent to get back the following:

```
cognito-identity:GetCredentialsForIdentity
cognito-identity:GetOpenIdToken
cognito-identity:GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity
connect:GetFederationToken
ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
gamelift:RequestUploadCredentials
s3:GetObject
secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
ssm:GetParameter
ssm:GetParameters
ssm:GetParametersByPath
sts:GetFederationToken
sts:GetSessionToken
```

But I am unable to achieve those results. In fact, using standard `sort | uniq` as well as all the `sort -k 2,2 -t:` and `LC_COLLATE=C sort` and similar variations I'm getting very much unsorted data returned. For example:

`| sort -u`, `LC_COLLATE=C sort`, and even `sort -k 1 -k 2 -t- | uniq` all result in this:

```
cognito-identity:GetOpenIdToken
s3:GetObject
cognito-identity:GetCredentialsForIdentity
...
```

The closest I've been able to come is using `| sort -k 2 -t- | uniq` to get:

```
s3:GetObject
connect:GetFederationToken
ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
gamelift:RequestUploadCredentials
secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
ssm:GetParameter
ssm:GetParameters
ssm:GetParametersByPath
sts:GetFederationToken
sts:GetSessionToken
cognito-identity:GetCredentialsForIdentity
cognito-identity:GetOpenIdToken
cognito-identity:GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity
```

...but that's still not even close to what I want or would expect.

Does anyone know how to make this work? I've looked for simple `awk` alternatives and would be happy with any working solution.

EDIT:

Responding to comment...

I'm manipulating a file, the full command I'm using, along with the added `LC_ALL=C cat -vet` you suggested (thanks for the tip!), looks like:

`cloudsplaining scan-policy-file --input-file $FILENAME.json | grep Actions | sed 's/Actions.*: //g' | tr ' ' '\n' | tr -d ',' | LC_ALL=C cat -vet`

```
^[[1msecretsmanager:GetSecretValue$
ssm:GetParameter$
ssm:GetParametersByPath$
s3:GetObject$
ssm:GetParameters$
^[[1mconnect:GetFederationToken$
gamelift:GetInstanceAccess$
cognito-identity:GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity$
ec2:GetPasswordData$
sts:GetSessionToken$
cognito-idp:GetSigningCertificate$
cognito-identity:GetCredentialsForIdentity$
ecr:GetAuthorizationToken$
cognito-identity:GetOpenIdToken$
sts:GetFederationToken$
^[[1ms3:GetObject$
secretsmanager:GetSecretValue$
ssm:GetParameter$
ssm:GetParameters$
ssm:GetParametersByPath$
```

So, yes, there is some junk. Not sure where it's coming from or why but I'd say that's definitely what's causing the issue and my confusion. Thanks for pointing that out...any idea on how to resolve it?

Edit 2 (resolved):

It was resolved after using the `| LC_ALL=C cat -vet` trick on the original output which showed me where the `[[1m` was coming from and ultimately, adding a preceding `.*` to my `sed` fixed it! As seen in this compared to the first edit:

`cloudsplaining scan-policy-file --input-file $FILENAME.json | grep Actions | sed 's/.*Actions.*: //g' | tr ' ' '\n' | tr -d ',' | LC_ALL=C cat -vet`

```
secretsmanager:GetSecretValue$
ssm:GetParameters$
ssm:GetParametersByPath$
s3:GetObject$
ssm:GetParameter$
ec2:GetPasswordData$
cognito-identity:GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity$
cognito-idp:GetSigningCertificate$
sts:GetFederationToken$
ecr:GetAuthorizationToken$
cognito-identity:GetCredentialsForIdentity$
gamelift:GetInstanceAccess$
cognito-identity:GetOpenIdToken$
connect:GetFederationToken$
sts:GetSessionToken$
s3:GetObject$
secretsmanager:GetSecretValue$
ssm:GetParameter$
ssm:GetParameters$
ssm:GetParametersByPath$
```

and now `| sort | uniq` work as expected as well. Lesson learned.

Comment: `sort -u` and `sort | uniq` both produce the expected result for me. Does your file have some sort of invisible characters or something messing it up? Try viewing it with `LC_ALL=C cat -vet filename` and see if that shows anything. It should add a `$` at the end of each line; anything other than that counts as "weird".

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks for pointing that out. I had no idea. I do see that there are some invisible characters. Updated my question to show the results.

Comment: @TryTryAgain Maybe you could remove the special character likes `^[[1m` or rewrite the original file likes `cat file > new_file` and then sort then by your rules, check it by "https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339513/how-to-remove-the-1m-22m-4m-24m-characters-while-keeping-the-newline".

Comment: Does `cloudsplaining` have an option to *not* colorize its output?

Comment: @GordonDavisson it does not but I see that's where it's coming from and when I removed the string I was not removing the `[[1m` .. prepending `.*` solves it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to think hard about what it is you want to sort. Essentially, it looks like you want to sort unique by the first field. For that you would use:

```
sort -t: -u -k1 file
```

The `-t:` sets the field separator, `-u` unique and `-k1` by the first key. (you can omit the `-k1` as that will be the default) So simply sorting with `sort -t: -u file` is fine.

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in `file`, you would receive:

```
$ sort -t: -u -k1 file
cognito-identity:GetCredentialsForIdentity
cognito-identity:GetOpenIdToken
cognito-identity:GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity
connect:GetFederationToken
ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
gamelift:RequestUploadCredentials
s3:GetObject
secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
ssm:GetParameter
ssm:GetParameters
ssm:GetParametersByPath
sts:GetFederationToken
sts:GetSessionToken
```

Which if I read your question correctly is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this should have and would have been working as expected all along.

The most useful bit of information was provided as a comment by @GordonDavisson stating:

> Does your file have some sort of invisible characters or something
> messing it up? Try viewing it with `LC_ALL=C cat -vet filename` and
> see if that shows anything. It should add a `$` at the end of each
> line; anything other than that counts as "weird".

Once I saw what was actually happening it was easy enough to fix. Details included in the OP's edits.